# empty request.POST with django form

Tags: python, django

I'm certain the answer is obvious, but I'm stuck.  I have a million and one forms in my django app, but for some reason this one is returning an empty request.POST (as seen in pdb).  What am I missing? Python 2.7, Django 1.7

```
<form action='{% url "create_jira_ticket" %}' method='post' id='create_jira_ticket_form'>
  {% csrf_token %}
    <a id='close_name_change_form' class="close">&times;</a>
    <label for="new_name">New name: </label>
    <input id="new_name" type="text" name="new_name" value="{{item.name}}">
    <input id='test' type='text' name='test'>
    <input type="hidden" value="10517" name="pid">
    <input type="hidden" name="pk" value="{{item.pk}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="model" value="{{item.meta.model_name}}">
    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="issuetype">
    <input type="hidden" value="5" name="priority">
    <input type="hidden" value="Change name of {{item.name}} to " name="summary" id='summary'>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{request.user}}" name="reporter">
    <input type="hidden" value="JoeBob" name="assignee">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="description" id="description">
    <input id='name_change_submit' class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" value="Create JIRA ticket">


</form>
```

views.py

```
def create_jira_ticket(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace() #request.POST already empty
    USER_AUTH = ('user', 'password')
    options = {'server': 'https://www.domain.net'}
    jira = JIRA(options)
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was just for testing.  Fixed.  Problem exists when method='post'.  I'm dumb, but not _that_ dumb.  :)

Comment: (for what it's worth, request.GET was also empty when method='get')

Comment: Provide the view, your form looks ok.

Comment: Just tried your code, it works.

Comment: Do you have some custom middlewares?

Comment: So, we just discovered that in pdb, request.POST is blank and !request.POST is correct.  Not sure why.